# How to change secondary DB to primary when use Sql Server HA alwayson and primary pc was disconnected

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

I am investigating trouble shooting in always-on environment of two computers.

If the primary's network was disconnect(not shutdown), the secondary's DB is unavailable.
It seems that the cluster is unable to determine the failure by quorum voting..

In this case, how can i promote secondary to primary and subordinate existing primary to secondary when a network problem is resolved

Comment: OT - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

First I would check the quorum settings on Windows Cluster, I assume your AlwaysOn is running on windows cluster.

To review your quorum setting: 
1. Launch Failover Cluster Manager
2. Connect to windows cluster 
3. Check quorum setting.